# SVG masks with transformation matrices

Tags: javascript, svg

Well, basically I have a SVG file which coordinates are calculated taking into account the screen resolution. Nonetheless, I have now a process that sends the SVG to another computer and adjusts each object to the resolution of the receiving computer. For that, I use the transformation matrix as you can see in object "OjeB0J0NzcPolyline1507". Everything went well, until now that I have to deal with masks.

Basically, the mask crops the SVG like if the mask was applied before the transformation and since the mask has a specific size, everything that is outside the mask is cropped. Nonetheless, I have already tried to make the svgjsRubberRect bigger and anything seems to work.

Is there any way to adjust the mask so the whole object is shown with exception to what is covered by the element"OjeB0J0NzcPath1519"

EDIT:

Original SVG:

```
<g id="canvas">
    <polyline fill="none" stroke-width="185" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="svg-selectable svg-editable svg-replaceable" mask="url('#zxjzF2hIO8Mask1276')" points="38,64 38,64 37,64 40,62 49,61 61,59 78,57 98,55 122,51 167,43 203,40 245,34 286,34 343,34 399,34 535,35 606,44 678,54 747,65 821,75 895,82 965,97 1036,103 1101,103 1157,103 1206,103 1252,103 1287,103 1322,95 1363,47 1265,27 1207,23 1159,16 1108,16 1062,14 1016,14 969,14 921,14 883,14 850,14 821,9 803,6 792,4 769,1 775,1 788,1 808,1 833,1 868,1 912,1 955,1 1005,6 1062,6 1296,32 1327,114 1250,123 1170,131 1070,134 960,134 844,134 712,134 580,134 432,134 286,134 152,134 12,134 0,134 0,147 0,158 0,168 0,172 8,172 27,172 51,172 81,172 122,172 157,172 260,172 325,172 398,172 487,172 578,172 665,172 846,179 918,189 1064,208 1125,216 1198,228 1213,233 1220,237 1215,245 1196,249 1154,256 1093,266 1016,277 923,284 707,284 592,284 462,284 330,284 190,284 58,284 0,284 0,286 0,277 0,276 0,275 0,276 3,278 9,282 17,283 47,286 74,286 112,286 161,286 220,286 301,286 482,286 590,286 703,286 946,286 1086,286 1337,298 1265,369 1144,369 1016,363 883,347 756,340 523,324 421,308 345,306 253,306 243,306 269,306 323,306 391,306 480,306 574,306 674,306 777,308 895,308 1104,312 1190,314 1263,314 1320,314 1343,314 1286,314 1217,307 1148,296 1085,288 995,275 981,270 974,266 973,266 973,264 977,261 996,256 1152,236 1217,232 1362,221 1335,214 1282,213 1266,213 1254,213 1242,215 1234,220 1232,225 1232,229 1232,233 1307,244 1364,226 1302,226 1226,226 857,226 654,227 557,232 150,276 68,287 11,306 0,331 0,336 0,337 1,337 3,339 10,339 14,341 19,343 21,343 24,343 26,343 28,343 30,342 33,342 53,342 87,339 219,348 288,354 362,365 428,375 500,386 688,412 733,420 788,429 804,437 804,441 768,456 713,466 547,477 72,477 0,477 0,461 0,454 19,454 71,454 128,454 203,454 295,454 406,452 519,448 1038,499 819,552 719,561 511,565 397,565 279,565 176,565 6,565 0,565 14,568 91,568 142,568 215,568 401,568 604,568 703,568 872,575 935,591" id="2HCqPWHVecPolyline1238"></polyline>
 </g>

 <defs id="zxjzF2hIO8Defs1001">
    <rect id="SvgjsRubberRect" width="800" height="1317" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" class="svg-reserved svg-rubber svg-replaceable"></rect>
    <path id="2HCqPWHVecPath1253" d="M212 177L212 177L217 177L235 179L243 179L268 179L280 179L319 163L362 155L386 155L398 155L496 177L507 182L528 187L560 196L611 211L667 221L677 222L721 228L730 228L762 228L794 229 " fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" class="svg-reserved svg-rubber svg-replaceable"></path>
    <mask id="zxjzF2hIO8Mask1276" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" class="svg-replaceable">
        <use id="zxjzF2hIO8Use1277" xlink:href="#SvgjsRubberRect"></use>
        <use id="zxjzF2hIO8Use1278" xlink:href="#2HCqPWHVecPath1253" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="10" > </use>
        </mask>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Scaled SVG:

```
<svg id="zxjzF2hIO8Svg1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<g id="canvas">
    <polyline transform="matrix(0.312592 0 0 0.462912 0 0)" fill="none" stroke-width="185" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="svg-selectable svg-editable svg-replaceable" mask="url('#zxjzF2hIO8Mask1276')" points="38,64 38,64 37,64 40,62 49,61 61,59 78,57 98,55 122,51 167,43 203,40 245,34 286,34 343,34 399,34 535,35 606,44 678,54 747,65 821,75 895,82 965,97 1036,103 1101,103 1157,103 1206,103 1252,103 1287,103 1322,95 1363,47 1265,27 1207,23 1159,16 1108,16 1062,14 1016,14 969,14 921,14 883,14 850,14 821,9 803,6 792,4 769,1 775,1 788,1 808,1 833,1 868,1 912,1 955,1 1005,6 1062,6 1296,32 1327,114 1250,123 1170,131 1070,134 960,134 844,134 712,134 580,134 432,134 286,134 152,134 12,134 0,134 0,147 0,158 0,168 0,172 8,172 27,172 51,172 81,172 122,172 157,172 260,172 325,172 398,172 487,172 578,172 665,172 846,179 918,189 1064,208 1125,216 1198,228 1213,233 1220,237 1215,245 1196,249 1154,256 1093,266 1016,277 923,284 707,284 592,284 462,284 330,284 190,284 58,284 0,284 0,286 0,277 0,276 0,275 0,276 3,278 9,282 17,283 47,286 74,286 112,286 161,286 220,286 301,286 482,286 590,286 703,286 946,286 1086,286 1337,298 1265,369 1144,369 1016,363 883,347 756,340 523,324 421,308 345,306 253,306 243,306 269,306 323,306 391,306 480,306 574,306 674,306 777,308 895,308 1104,312 1190,314 1263,314 1320,314 1343,314 1286,314 1217,307 1148,296 1085,288 995,275 981,270 974,266 973,266 973,264 977,261 996,256 1152,236 1217,232 1362,221 1335,214 1282,213 1266,213 1254,213 1242,215 1234,220 1232,225 1232,229 1232,233 1307,244 1364,226 1302,226 1226,226 857,226 654,227 557,232 150,276 68,287 11,306 0,331 0,336 0,337 1,337 3,339 10,339 14,341 19,343 21,343 24,343 26,343 28,343 30,342 33,342 53,342 87,339 219,348 288,354 362,365 428,375 500,386 688,412 733,420 788,429 804,437 804,441 768,456 713,466 547,477 72,477 0,477 0,461 0,454 19,454 71,454 128,454 203,454 295,454 406,452 519,448 1038,499 819,552 719,561 511,565 397,565 279,565 176,565 6,565 0,565 14,568 91,568 142,568 215,568 401,568 604,568 703,568 872,575 935,591" id="2HCqPWHVecPolyline1238"></polyline>
 </g>

 <defs id="zxjzF2hIO8Defs1001">
    <rect id="SvgjsRubberRect" width="800" height="1317" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" class="svg-reserved svg-rubber svg-replaceable"></rect>
    <path id="2HCqPWHVecPath1253" d="M212 177L212 177L217 177L235 179L243 179L268 179L280 179L319 163L362 155L386 155L398 155L496 177L507 182L528 187L560 196L611 211L667 221L677 222L721 228L730 228L762 228L794 229 " fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" class="svg-reserved svg-rubber svg-replaceable" transform="matrix(0.312592 0 0 0.462912 0 0)"></path>
    <mask id="zxjzF2hIO8Mask1276" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" class="svg-replaceable">
        <use id="zxjzF2hIO8Use1277" xlink:href="#SvgjsRubberRect"></use>
        <use id="zxjzF2hIO8Use1278" xlink:href="#2HCqPWHVecPath1253" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="10" transform="matrix(3.19906 0 0 2.16024 0 0)"> </use>
        </mask>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please provide a working example of your SVG so that we can better see the problem.  When I try your SVG nothing is visible - even without the transform.  Also, you have HTML entities ("&quot;") in your SVG file.

Comment: Thanks in advance for your help. I have already changed the SVG to a working one like you requested. If you try it in a browser, and resize the browser window, you will notice that the mask crops the image more than the size of the window.

Comment: I can't tell from what you posted whether it is the pre-transform, or post-transformed version. Please post the original SVG and your attempt at scaling it, then we might be able to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: The original SVG has no transform matrices..as I edited

Comment: I just see a black rectangle.

Comment: you should see a black rectangle with some white path... But well, nevermind, I have an idea to turn around this problem. Thanks for trying ;)